# How to split a single column data by a specific expression?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Pandas and Python Gurus,**

I have a single column data, with several information (changing all the time) and I'll love to separate by areas of expression, example:

Currently using the pandas.read_cvs to pull data into DF.

```
# Add the dependencies.
import pandas as pd
import os

# Files to load
Raw_Data_load = os.path.join("Resources", "Raw_Data.csv")

# Read the raw data file and store it in a Pandas DataFrame.
raw_data_df = pd.read_csv(Raw_Data_load)
raw_data_df
```

| Raw Data |
| --- |
| Sun Jan 11 07:46:33 -0600 [LKSDFLKLKJF-56: bacml: warn:error]: Address failed 7a-123478563412. Reason: Failed to access remote. |
| Mon Feb 21 13:31:45 -0400 [LHHKJLKJD-01: repi_exemptXY: create.done:info]: params: {'1', 'app'}: |
| Thu May 15 12:33:06 -0500 [DRHHFJJHS-08: UDPAgentRead: SessionFailed:debug]: Session Manager (999) failed |

**And I'll like the data separate like the below:**

| Data | Time | AZ | Error | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sun Jan 11 07:46:33 | -0600 | [LKSDFLKLKJF-56: | bacml: warn:error]: Address failed 7a-123478563412. | Reason: Failed to access remote. |
| Mon Feb 21 13:31:45 | -0400 | [LHHKJLKJD-01: | repi_exemptXY: create.done:info]: | params: {'1', 'app'}: |
| Thu May 15 12:33:06 | -0500 | [DRHHFJJHS-08: | UDPAgentRead: SessionFailed:debug]: | Session Manager (999) failed |

Please Note:
Raw data is different, changes date, time, AZ, Error and Action.

**Big question here using Pandas:**

> **How can I tell my script to separate from Raw Data to Clean Data as**
> **per example above?**

Comment: If the data is changing all the time, you should provide more than a single example

Comment: Are you reading your file via pd.read_csv? In case you do, did you use the sep expression, https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: @mozway thanks for your reply, I did an update to my question. Hope that helps to clarify the same.

Comment: You might need to build a custom parser to parse each line. Ex: if you separate each row in raw data by spaces into tokens, first 3 token in data, 4th and 5th one is Time and AZ respectively. For Error and Action, you can come up based on your data as I couldn't distinguish them seeing the 3 rows.